# Buscar en un array - JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy intentando crear un array con los nombres de 5 alumnos, posteriormente un array con las notas de dichos alumnos. El programa solicitará el nombre del alumno, y devolverá su nota.

Este es el código actual:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b,c,d,e; //VARIABLES ARRAY
        String f,p;
        
        a = 7;
        b = 9;
        c = 7;
        d = 8;
        e = 10;
        
        
                
        //Declaraciones arrays.
        int intArray[]; //declaramos como tipo int al array
        String twoArray[];
        
        //Asignamos tamaÃ±o.
        intArray = new int[5]; //asignamos el tamaÃ±o del array [5]
        twoArray = new String[5];
        
        //Asignamos datos al array.
        intArray[0] = a;
        intArray[1] = b;
        intArray[2] = c;
        intArray[3] = d;
        intArray[4] = e;
        
        twoArray[0] = "Manolo";
        twoArray[1] = "Juan";
        twoArray[2] = "Maria";
        twoArray[3] = "Jose Luís";
        twoArray[4] = "Sara";
        
        System.out.println("Escriba el nombre del alumno: ");
        p = s.nextLine();
        
        for(int x = 0; x < twoArray.length; x++){
            if(twoArray[0].equals("Manolo")){
                System.out.println("La nota de Manolo es: " + intArray[0]);
                break;
            }
            else{
                if(twoArray[1].equals("Juan")){
                    System.out.println("La nota de Juan es: " + intArray[1]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(twoArray[2].equals("Maria")){
                System.out.println("La nota de Juan es: " + intArray[2]);
                break;
            }
            else{
                if(twoArray[3].equals("Jose Luis")){
                    System.out.println("La nota de Jose Luís es: " + intArray[3]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(twoArray[4].equals("Sara")){
                System.out.println("La nota de Sara es: " + intArray[4]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Necesito crear un bucle, que vaya recorriendo el array de nombres, y viendo si el nombre esta: if (aray [i].equals(nombrebuscado)) Si se cumple, me guardaré en una variable la posicion, que es la i. Pero no se como hacerlo, cuando intentas poner un usuario no te pone el usuario que quieres, solo te sale el primero (Manolo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu enfoque está bien pero no lo terminas de llevar hasta el final.

Por un lado pides al usuario que introduzca el nombre del que mostrar la nota y lo guardas en la variable `p`:

```
System.out.println("Escriba el nombre del alumno: ");
p = s.nextLine();
```

Pero luego no la usas en el `for`.

Tu bucle debería ser algo así:

```
//Con esta variable vamos a controlar si el alumno existe o no.
boolean encontrado = false;
for(int x = 0; x < twoArray.length; x++){
    //Si el elemento x del array es igual al nombre introducido
    if( twoArray[x].equals(p)) {
        System.out.println("La nota de " + p + " es: " + intArray[x]);
        encontrado = true;
        break;
    }
}
//Con este if podrías saber si al terminar el bucle se encontró al alumno.
if( !encontrado) {
    System.out.pirntln( "El alumno " + p + " no tiene nota.");
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias compañero por la ayuda!! Me ha funcionado, sobre todo, gracias por la explicación con los comentarios ;) Muy útil para entenderlo! Gracias!